# Billingsley Probability and Measure Section 3 Theorem 3.3, 3.4

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is from Probability and Measure, Billingsley, 3rd edition, page 43. It is right after theorem 3.2 and theorem 3.3 have been proved.

Note that the $\pi$-$\lambda$  theorem and the concept of $\lambda$-system are exactly what are needed to make this proof work: The essential property of probability measures is countable additivity, and this is a condition on countable disjoint unions, the only kind involved in the requirement ($\lambda$-3) in the definition of $\lambda$-system. In this, as in many applications of the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, $\mathscr{L} \subset \sigma{(\mathscr{P})} $ and therefore $\sigma{(\mathscr{P})} =\mathscr{L}$,even though the relation $\mathscr{L} \subset \sigma{(\mathscr{P})}$itself suffices for the conclusion of the theorem.

Theorem 3.2 proves that if $\mathscr{P}$  is a $\pi$ system and $\mathscr{L}$ is a lambda system such that $\mathscr{P} \subset \mathscr{L}$, then $\sigma({\mathscr{P}} )\subset \mathscr{L}$ .

Theorem 3.3 : If $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ are probability measures on $\sigma({\mathscr{P}})$, such that they agree on the $\mathscr{P}$, which is a $\pi$ system, then they agree on $\sigma({\mathscr{P}})$.

I cannot understand how we can deduce that $\mathscr{L} \subset \sigma{(\mathscr{P})}$ and go on to say that these two sets are equal.  Are these two sets equal from the point of the probability measure defined on them? I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In measure theory, you are often in the situation where you want to prove that a property holds for any set belonging to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal T$. So you naturally set
$$
\mathcal L:=\{{A\in\mathcal T\vert\ \textrm{The property holds for A}}\},
$$
and your objective is to show that $\mathcal T\subset\mathcal L$, or equivalently $\mathcal T=\mathcal L$. It is frequent to be in a situation where:

- $\mathcal T=\sigma(\mathcal P)$, where $\mathcal P$ is a $\pi$-system;
- $\mathcal L$ is a $\lambda$-system.

Then by the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem (Theorem 3.2), $\mathcal P\subset L$ iff $\mathcal T\subset\mathcal L$.

So the challenge here is only to find if you can, among all $\pi$-systems $\mathcal P$ which generate $\mathcal T$ (i.e.$\mathcal T=\sigma(\mathcal P)$), one that is included in $\mathcal L$. If you can, then the proof is finished.

So to recapitulate and highlight the connection with your question:

- The inclusion $\mathcal L\subset\sigma(\mathcal P)$ is just a trivial consequence of the definition of $\mathcal L$;
- The (often more interesting and conclusive) inclusion $\sigma(\mathcal P)\subset\mathcal L$ is a consequence of the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem.

For instance in Theorem 3.3, you want to show that $P_1$ and $P_2$ agree on $\sigma(\mathcal P)$. So you set $\mathcal L:=\{A\in\sigma(\mathcal P)\vert P_1(A)=P_2(A)\}$ and complete the proof by showing that $\sigma(\mathcal P)\subset\mathcal L$ (the inclusion $\mathcal L\subset\sigma(\mathcal P)$ here is trivial consequence of the fact that $\mathcal L$ is defined as a subset of $\sigma(\mathcal P)$). From the preceding discussion we see that the proof is complete as soon as we prove that $\mathcal P\subset \mathcal L$ and $\mathcal L$ is a $\lambda$-system. The inclusion $\mathcal P\subset \mathcal L$ is nothing else than the assumption of Theorem 3.3 ($P_1$ and $P_2$ agree on $\mathcal P$), and the fact that $\mathcal L$ is a $\lambda$-system is an easy consequence of the properties which define probability measures, as shown by Billingsley.